# Can I somehow tidy up this (overuse?) of generics?

Tags: c#, generics, type-safety

I'm building a generic flat file reader which looks something like this.

```
 public class GenericReader<TComposite, THeader, TData, TTrailer> 
    where TComposite : GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>, new()
    where THeader : new()
    where TData : new()
    where TTrailer : new()
{
    public TComposite Read()
    { 
        // read stuff, do parsing etc
        var composite = new TComposite();

        composite.Header = new THeader();
        composite.Data = new TData();
        composite.Trailer = new TTrailer();

        return composite;
    }        
}
```

It could be consumed like so.

```
var reader = new GenericReader<Composite<Header, Data, Trailer>, Header, Data, Trailer> ();

var composite = reader.Read();
Console.WriteLine(composite.Data.SomeProperty);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Here are the classes used.

```
public class Composite<THeader, TData, TTrailer> : GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>
{

}

public class GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>
{
    public THeader Header { get; set; }

    public TData Data { get; set; }

    public TTrailer Trailer { get; set; }
}

public class Header {
    public string SomeProperty { get { return "SomeProperty"; } } 
}

public class Data {
    public string SomeProperty { get { return "SomeProperty"; } } 
}

public class Trailer {
    public string SomeProperty { get { return "SomeProperty"; } } 
}
```

Is there a way how I could remove or encapsulate that generic type information in the GenericReader? I'm looking for an extra pair of eyes to show me something what I've been missing. We already did something with returning interfaces, and making the consumer do a cast, but that just moves the responsibility to the wrong location in my opinion, plus there is a small performance penalty.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the thinking behind the Composite and GenericComposite classes?  They seem the same to me.

Comment: What's the intent of the Composite class in the first place? Why is that separate from the GenericReader?

Comment: Composite class composites header, data and trailer, makes for one thing to return. You can see it as a logical file.

Comment: @JeffVanzella You're absolutely right, it's not necessary. Now I can remove that first type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Having so many `new` operations -- seems like you'd want to use some kind of a factory, injected in the constructor, or the instances themselves injected in the constructor, instead of constructing the classes *inside* the constructor.

Comment: The real imp uses a factory to create the instances. I'm doing more than composing my composite.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply replace

```
public class GenericReader<TComposite, THeader, TData, TTrailer> 
    where TComposite : GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>, new()
    where THeader : new()
    where TData : new()
    where TTrailer : new()
{
    public TComposite Read()
    {
        // read stuff, do parsing etc 
        var composite = new TComposite();

        composite.Header = new THeader();
        composite.Data = new TData();
        composite.Trailer = new TTrailer();

        return composite;
    }        
}
```

with

```
public class GenericReader<THeader, TData, TTrailer> 
    where THeader : new()
    where TData : new()
    where TTrailer : new()
{
    public GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer> Read()
    {
        // read stuff, do parsing etc 
        var composite = new GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>();

        composite.Header = new THeader();
        composite.Data = new TData();
        composite.Trailer = new TTrailer();

        return new composite;
    }        
}
```

?

Comment: Because I didn't see it. How can I look over that? Thank you, changing that right now.

Comment: Sometimes, it just takes another pair of eyes.  I've certainly been there, and that's exactly what this SE site is for!  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to create a factory type class.  The create would take the 3 generics as generics, and the expected return type as a parameter.  Then use reflection to create the instance.  Before you say anything about using reflection, by creating generics in your function, you are inadvertently using reflection.

```
public class CompsiteFactory
{
    public GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer> Create<THeader, TData, TTrailer>(Type compositeType)
        where THeader : new()
        where TData : new()
        where TTrailer : new()
    {
        var finalType =
            compositeType.MakeGenericType(new[] {typeof (THeader), typeof (TData), typeof (TTrailer)});

        var compositeInstance =
            (GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer>)
            Activator.CreateInstance(finalType);

        compositeInstance.Header = new THeader();
        compositeInstance.Data = new TData();
        compositeInstance.Trailer = new TTrailer();

        return compositeInstance;
    }
}
```

Modify your GenericReader

```
public class GenericReader<THeader, TData, TTrailer>
    where THeader : new()
    where TData : new()
    where TTrailer : new()
{
    private readonly CompsiteFactory _factory;

    public GenericReader(CompsiteFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public GenericComposite<THeader, TData, TTrailer> Read(Type compositeType)
    {
        return _factory.Create<THeader, TData, TTrailer>(compositeType);
    }
}

var factory = new CompsiteFactory();
var genericReader = new GenericReader<Header, Data, Trailer>(factory);

var composite = genericReader.GenericComposite(typeof(Composite<,,>));
```

And you have your instance of GenericComposite.

I know that is not a true factory class, but it will work for this instance.  If you want to do it properly, there is a lot of examples on best practices online.

Comment: I'm doing more than composing my instance. The real imp uses something that creates the record instances.

Comment: @JefClaes. If your doing more than what you are asking for in your review, perhaps post the real impl so reviewers have the real question to work off....

Comment: @dreza - I think that's what the improperly formatted comment is supposed to indicate is happening in there.

Comment: What do you do with the record instances?

Comment: @dreza I'm sorry, I put that in there from my mobile phone. Couldn't get it right.

Comment: @JeffVanzella We convert them to XML in a consuming class.